# HtmlAttributeName doesn't take effect

Tags: .net, .net-8.0

I just upgraded to .NET8 so I dropped Newtonsoft.Json. Unfortunately, I have a problem with HTML serialisation. HtmlAttributeName don't take any effect.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

Serialized class

```
public class ToolTip
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("tooltipText")]
    [JsonPropertyName("tooltipText")]
    public string TooltipText { get; set; }
    
    [HtmlAttributeName("template")]
    [JsonPropertyName("template")]
    public string Template { get; set; }
}
```

Output.cshtml

```
<div class="control-wrapper">
    <div id="rteSection">
        <ejs-richtexteditor id="@Model.Id" e="" actionBegin="handleFullScreen" enableHtmlSanitizer="false" created="created" quickToolbarOpen="quickToolbarOpenEvent" change="change" focus="focus" saveInterval="1000" height="500" format="@Model.Format" toolbarClick="toolbarClicked">
            <e-richtexteditor-toolbarsettings items="@Model.Items"></e-richtexteditor-toolbarsettings>
            <e-richtexteditor-quicktoolbarsettings link="@Model.QuickToolbarLinkItems"></e-richtexteditor-quicktoolbarsettings>
            <e-richtexteditor-iframesettings enable="true"></e-richtexteditor-iframesettings>
            <e-richtexteditor-pastecleanupsettings plainText="true" allowedStyleProps="null"></e-richtexteditor-pastecleanupsettings>
            <e-content-template>
                @Model.Value
            </e-content-template>
        </ejs-richtexteditor>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output is `TooltipText` and `Template`. What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you are saying it worked with Newtonsoft.Json, can you show how this differs from the previous???

Comment: @dragon When I add this into Startup.cs it works.

services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });

Comment: What is "HTML serialization"? Can you please create a [mre] and post it somewhere like github?